# Organizing github stars

Tags: github, open-source

I have lots of repos on GitHub which I starred for later use.
Is there any tool that can organize a collection for stargazers so they can browse what they had starred? For example, find which components I have starred for iOS animations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an attempt I just came across: [Gitrep](http://gitrep.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Since the [starred API](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-repositories-being-starred) doesn't offer any filter, that means you will have to filter the JSON response.

Something like:

```
$.each(data.data, function(key, val) {
  if (val.language == "ios") {
    $.each(val.payload.commits, function(key2, val2) {
      list.append('<li id="' + val.name + '"><a href="' + val.html_url + '">' + val.full_name + '</a></li>');
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [OhMyStar](http://www.ohmystarapp.com). It is a good app for organise Github stars and see others' stars.